# Is there a way to stagger the launch of VM's in virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Virtual box to run some MS-DOS machines, I find if I tag them all to launch at startup Virtual Box seems to trip over its feet, i end up having to kill it, restart, and launch the VM's manually.

So I need to either postpone all the launches until VB is fully up and running, or stagger the start of individual VM's to one at a time maybe.

A

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-autostart) you can from the commandline, something like

```
vboxmanage modifyvm  <vmname> --autostart-delay <seconds>
```

Comment: I'll check into it, I didn't find that. Ta